# Why does my C# AJAX request work with HTTP and fail with HTTPS?

Tags: c#, django, nginx, dotnet-httpclient, django-allauth

I have a django application working with django-allauth.

I also have it deployed with HTTPS in a production environment.

AJAX queries from the web browser pointing at the HTTPS site for logging in using a POST to '/accounts/login/' return JSON back as expected.

The problem lies with my C# mobile code (Xamarin based).

```
_client = new HttpClient(handler) {BaseAddress = uri};
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

When the 'uri' used as the BaseAddress is http and points to my development server, everything works fine, and I get JSON back in the response.

However when the uri points to my https site (sitting behind nginx and gunicorn), I get an HTML response back.

No idea why this is happening.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: When you get an HTML response back from a web servie it often indicates it has thrown some kind of error. What is the content of the HTML.

Answer (score 5):

OK, finally found the answer.  And boy is it a goodie.

https://serverfault.com/questions/508524/preserve-http-headers-from-django-using-nginx-and-gunicorn pointed me to the interesting nginx setting.

underscores_in_headers on;

By default, nginx blocks any headers that have underscores in them, as mentioned here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

This had me wondering "why are requests from the web browser working but not my C# client?", and the answer is subtle.

In the Chromium developer network tab, I noticed that the header sent from the browser was "X-Requested-With".  This was being mapped by nginx (I think) to "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" in the proxy_pass part, which is exactly what django is looking for.

I made one change in the C# code to get it working.  I changed:

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

to

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-REQUESTED-WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

And it started working.

I hope this stays around for future people having this problem.

Comment: It's a very good answer so I'm sure it'll stay here for a long time.